# Old MySql libraries PhpMyAdmin on OpenShift

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift

I have an application on openshift with MySql and PhpMyAdmin. After some time i get this advert on phpmyadmin "Le tue librerie di PHP per MySQL versione 5.1.73 sono diverse dalla versione di MySQL server 5.5.50. Potrebbe causare comportamenti imprevedibili." which means that my PHP libs are old for the MYSQL server. 
Now every operation that i try gives me a "Token Mismatch" error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? The version mismatch, while a rather drastic difference, probably isn't the cause of your token mismatch error.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and any related cookies (which start with "pma"). Make sure the webserver session folder is readable and writable by the webserver and PHP processes. Any hints in the webserver error log? Which phpMyAdmin version is this?